# Does the exponential operator $e^{tA}$ defined via functional calculus and via semi group coincide?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators, functional-calculus

Given $X$ is a Hilbert space and consider the operator $A$ on $X$.

Functional calculus:
given an unbounded operator $A$ (densely defined, closed and self-adjoint), we can define $e^{tA}$ by the spectral measure.

Semi-group:
given an unbounded operator $A$ (densely defined, closed) which generates a continuous semi-group, we can define $e^{tA}$ by the Laplace transform of the resolvent operator.

Question:
Do these two approaches give the same definition in the case where $A$ is densely defined, closed, self-adjoint and generates a continuous semi-group?

Trivial case: if $A$ is bounded or $A$ has compact resolvent, I think this question is rather trivial in view of the behavior of the point spectrum.

Comment: The answer is of course yes.  See Rudin's Functional Analysis, Theorems 13.35, 13.36 and 13.38.